# Oval validation framework - Implementation of @javax.validation.constraints.Pattern (dont working)

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-batch, oval

i'm making a validation with Oval. I'm using spring batch to populate(csv to object) an object and validating it with Oval. But i think my @javax.validation.constraints.Pattern is not working, because my console doesn't show an error when i run the program.

Here are my clases:

Client.jaba

```
package com.mistaiker;



import net.sf.oval.constraint.Length;
import net.sf.oval.constraint.MinLength;
import net.sf.oval.constraint.NotEmpty;
import net.sf.oval.constraint.NotNegative;
import net.sf.oval.constraint.NotNull;


public class Client {

    //Atributos
    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    @MinLength(value = 1)
    @Length(max=4)
    @javax.validation.constraints.Pattern(regexp = "[a-zA-Z]")
    private String title;

    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    @MinLength(value = 1)
    @Length(max=20)
    @javax.validation.constraints.Pattern(regexp = "[a-zA-Z]")
    private String firstName;

    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    @MinLength(value = 1)
    @Length(max=20)
    @javax.validation.constraints.Pattern(regexp = "^[a-zA-Z]")
    private String surname;

    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    @NotNegative
    @MinLength(value = 10)
    @Length(max=10)
    @javax.validation.constraints.Pattern(regexp = "[0-9]")
    private long regNum;

    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    @NotNegative 
    @MinLength(value = 2)
    @Length(max=2)
    @javax.validation.constraints.Pattern(regexp = "[0-9]")
    private int assigment_1;

    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    @NotNegative
    @MinLength(value = 2)
    @Length(max=2)
    @javax.validation.constraints.Pattern(regexp = "[0-9]")
    private int assigment_2;

    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    @NotNegative
    @MinLength(value = 2)
    @Length(max=2)
    @javax.validation.constraints.Pattern(regexp = "[0-9]")
    private int assigment_3;

    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    @MinLength(value = 1)
    @Length(max=30)
    @javax.validation.constraints.Pattern(regexp = "[0-9a-zA-Z]")
    private String address;


    //metodos
    void showData(){
        System.out.println(title + "\t" + firstName + "\t" + surname + "\t" +
                            regNum + "\t" + assigment_1 + "\t" + assigment_2 + "\t" +
                            assigment_3 +  "\t" + address);
    }

    //Getters y setters
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }
    public void setSurname(String surname) {
        this.surname = surname;
    }
    public long getRegNum() {
        return regNum;
    }
    public void setRegNum(long regNum) {
        this.regNum = regNum;
    }
    public int getAssigment_1() {
        return assigment_1;
    }
    public void setAssigment_1(int assigment_1) {
        this.assigment_1 = assigment_1;
    }
    public int getAssigment_2() {
        return assigment_2;
    }
    public void setAssigment_2(int assigment_2) {
        this.assigment_2 = assigment_2;
    }
    public int getAssigment_3() {
        return assigment_3;
    }
    public void setAssigment_3(int assigment_3) {
        this.assigment_3 = assigment_3;
    }
    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }
    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }



}
```

ClientFieldSetMapper.java

```
package com.mistaiker;

import org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.FieldSetMapper;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.FieldSet;
import org.springframework.validation.BindException;

public class ClientFieldSetMapper implements FieldSetMapper<Client>{

    @Override
    public Client mapFieldSet(FieldSet fieldSet) throws BindException {

        Client client = new Client();

        client.setTitle(fieldSet.readRawString(0));
        client.setFirstName(fieldSet.readRawString(1));
        client.setSurname(fieldSet.readRawString(2));
        client.setRegNum(fieldSet.readLong(3));
        client.setAssigment_1(fieldSet.readInt(4));
        client.setAssigment_2(fieldSet.readInt(5));
        client.setAssigment_3(fieldSet.readInt(6));
        client.setAddress(fieldSet.readRawString(7));

        return client;
    }

}
```

App.java

```
package com.mistaiker;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import net.sf.oval.ConstraintViolation;
import net.sf.oval.Validator;

import org.springframework.batch.item.ExecutionContext;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ParseException;
import org.springframework.batch.item.UnexpectedInputException;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.DefaultLineMapper;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineTokenizer;
import org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource;

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        FlatFileItemReader<Client> itemReader = new FlatFileItemReader<Client>();
        itemReader.setResource(new FileSystemResource("C:/Users/juan.m.palazzolo/Desktop/data.csv"));   

        DefaultLineMapper<Client> lineMapper = new DefaultLineMapper<Client>();
        lineMapper.setLineTokenizer(new DelimitedLineTokenizer());
        lineMapper.setFieldSetMapper(new ClientFieldSetMapper());
        itemReader.setLineMapper(lineMapper);
        itemReader.open(new ExecutionContext());

        Client client = new Client();
        ArrayList<Client> clients = new ArrayList<>();

        try {
            client = itemReader.read();

            //validation!!
            Validator validator = new Validator();//Validator object
            List<ConstraintViolation> violations = validator.validate(client);


            if(violations.size()>0)
            {
//              Log.severe("Object " + client + " is invalid.");
//              throw new BussinessException(violations);
                System.out.println("error en validacion");

            }



            while(client != null){

                client.showData();

                clients.add(client);

                client = itemReader.read();

                if(client != null){
                violations = validator.validate(client);}


                //validation!!


                if(violations.size()>0)
                {
                    //LOG.severe("Object " + client + " is invalid.");
                    //throw new BussinessException(violations);
                    System.out.println("error en validacion");
                }
            }

        } catch (UnexpectedInputException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        /*for(Client x: clients){
            x.showData();
        }*/

    }


}
```

this is my csv:

```
Mr,juan,mik2e,1234567891,75,84,80,Flat 1a\\The Street\\The Town
Mr,John,Smith,1234567892,68,57,72,Flat 1b\\The Street\\The Town
Mr,Zack,Watts,1234567893,32,43,49,Flat 1c\\The Street\\The Town
Mrs,Hillary,Rix,1234567894,87,88,86,Flat 1d\\The Street\\The Town
Miss,Zoe,Adams,1234567895,52,48,57,Flat 1e\\The Street\\The Town
Mr,Andy,Brown,1234567896,42,52,54,Flat 1f\\The Street\\The Town
```

Comment: And why should it? Pattern only works for text based properties not numerics, dates etc. So basically on `String` will work. Your others are pretty much useless.

Answer (score 0):

You need to activate interpretation of bean validation constraints as documented at http://oval.sourceforge.net/userguide.html#interpreting-bean-validation-annotations

```
// configure OVal to interprete OVal constraint annotations as well as built-in JSR303 annotations
Validator validator = new Validator(new AnnotationsConfigurer(), new BeanValidationAnnotationsConfigurer());
```